# How to zoom and scroll SVGs in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, svg, zooming, vaadin, vaadin7

I created a SVG image in java with batik and I managed to display it with vaadin embedded.

```
// Get a DOMImplementation
DOMImplementation domImpl =
        GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
String svgNamespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

// Create an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document
Document document = 
domImpl.createDocument(svgNamespaceURI, "svg", null);
svgGen = new SVGGraphics2D(document);

svgGen.setPaint(Color.green);
svgGen.drawPolyline(new int[]{70, 70, 30}, new int[]{50, 30, 70}, 3);
```

Displaying the SVG in vaadin

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
svgGen.stream(writer, useCSS);

StreamSource source = new StreamSource() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4905654404647215809L;

        public InputStream getStream() {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        }
    };
// create a StreamResource 
String filename = "svg" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".svg";
StreamResource stream = new StreamResource(source, filename);

embedded= new Embedded();
embedded.setSizeFull();
embedded.setMimeType("image/svg+xml");
embedded.setSource(stream);       

mainLayout.addComponent(embedded);
```

I now want to zoom and scroll the image and expected the Embedded to provide this functionality. 
After searching for a while I haven't found a working solution so far.

The Question is, how can I enable scrolling and zooming the SVG-Image?

Comment: The `Embedded`vaadin component is just a container for images of any kind. It does not add other functionality to the image. Have you a example of such a svg "navigation"?

Comment: The only example I have is panZoom in javascript, but I'm not sure how to implement it in java or use it with the embedded svg